# HTML5 application cache updating solution

Tags: html, application-cache

I may get some heat for this question because there are a lot out there already.

BUT... Every question has a different answer and no finite answer seems to be solid.

SO THE QUESTION... If I update a file which is reference in the application cache manifest for an offline available application, how can i force the update of the manifest and the offline cache without changing the manifest?

I hope this is clear. To show that I have done some research:

[How to properly invalidate an HTML5 Cache Manifest for online/offline web apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715568/how-to-properly-invalidate-an-html5-cache-manifest-for-online-offline-web-apps)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8211563/491044

[Updating the cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/#toc-updating-cache) This requires a change to the manifest though...

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  You must update the manifest file.  Be careful to set an immediate expiry header on your manifest file so that the browser recognizes there's been an update to it.

Comment: Most posts I have read seem to insist that the browsers (Opera and FF) ignore the expiry date. This seems to easy a solution for a topic which has so many Q&As. I will try it myself as I have not yet. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @trgraglia Check out the [expiry settings in HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess#L229).

Comment: That combined with a datetime and version comment update in the manifest seems to do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: I'm convinced there is still something else that is missing. I update the manifest every time a file in it changes, and apache emits the proper headers to prevent caching, yet intermittently Firefox refuses the load the updated file even after looking at the new manifest.